# How to make the label grow - XAMARIN

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

i have a Picker that picks the values from a list of strings, i can store the string into a list and save the picks that the user is doing. The thing is how can i show the user this values? like is there some way i can have a label and everytime a user picks a string from the list it goes into that label showing to the user what picks he did?

This is how i store the picks:

```
       private void _picker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        us.Add(new Users { user = _picker.SelectedItem.ToString() });
    }
```

This is my try(do not even work ahah):

```
        StackLayout sl = new StackLayout();

        _picker = new Picker();
        _picker.Title = "Escolha o/os destinatários";
        _picker.ItemsSource = users;
        _picker.SelectedIndexChanged += _picker_SelectedIndexChanged;
        sl.Children.Add(_picker);

        _label = new Label();
        _label.Text = _picker.SelectedItem.ToString();
        sl.Children.Add(_label);

        Content = sl;
```

Thanks any help.

Comment: You can achieve this by using a bindable object, create and set a bindable object to your label then on **_picker_SelectedIndexChanged** method you can update the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a simple app for you to understand this.

```
 <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Picker x:Name="picker" SelectedIndexChanged="picker_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Picker.Items>
                <x:String>Hello</x:String>
                <x:String>Hello World</x:String>
            </Picker.Items>
        </Picker>

        <Label x:Name="label" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

And in the selectedIndexChanged method just write this.

```
private void picker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label.Text += picker.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I think what the OP wants is `+=` not `=` in the selectedindexchanged method. He wants the label to "grow". other than that, i believe this is fine